# If statement from variable in PHP

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I want to write an if statement in a variable then want to run it, like this.

```
$Statement = "$Name == 'John' AND $Age == '28'";
if ($Statement) {
    echo "Something";
}
```

Please help me for solve this

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
$Statement = ($Name == 'John' && $Age == '28');
```

This will immediately run the IF clause and set the value of $Statement to true / false
or this:

```
function Statement($Name,$Age){
return ($Name == 'John' && $Age == '28')
}
```

This will let you use your if statement over and over without having to rewrite it, just use the function inside an if.
That should give you the portability you need.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple syntax. You should probably have a look through the manual here, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

```
$name = 'John';
$age = 28;

if($name == 'John' && $age == 28) {
    echo '...';
}
```

The above code should be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but I'm not asking about this.

Comment: Is it possible to use this statement from a variable? I mean this statement will be dynamic. Thanks

Comment: This works correctly, but is not what the OP asked about. You should fully read and understand the question before answering.

Comment: This is possible but __NOT RECOMMENDED__ You should explain why do you need this